# How can I overwrite an older version of Newtonsoft.Json via NuGet?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, nuget, dependency-management

I have a solution with the following structure:

- My.sln

  - 1.csproj
  - 2.csproj

*1* has a dependency on a legacy *NuGet* package *foo*, *foo* then has an older version of *Newtonsoft.Json* included in the package as a *dll* instead of taking a dependency to the *Newtonsoft.Json* *NuGet* package.

*1* also has a direct dependency to the latest version of *Newtonsoft.Json* *Nuget* package.

*2* has a dependency on *1* and also has a *NuGet* dependency on the latest version of *Newtonsoft.Json*.

The build order of the solution also ensures that *1* is built before *2*.

Therefore I expect the latest version of *Newtonsoft.Json* to be coppied to the output folder however the older version referenced by *1* is coppied instead.

How can I resolve this?

Please note this question is not related to *Assembly Binding Redirect* that is another issue which I have already fixed and tested. The main issue now is ensuring the latest version of *Newtonsoft.json* *dll* is coppied to the output folder.

Also note that we have no control over how the legacy *foo* package is authored.

Comment: @mjwills, updated the question.

Comment: Does 1 currently take an explicit dependency on Netwonsoft.Json? if not: could it? (transitive dependencies are fun...)

Comment: @MarcGravell, if by explicit you mean _NuGet_ dependency on the latest version of _Newtonsoft.Json_, then yes it does.

Comment: this is odd; I would have *expected* it to be the current version in the output folder :/